# How to remove the last occurring comma, the comma itself may not be the last character from a String in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace

The table structure is like this :-

```
mysql> select * from formjson;
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
| id | jsonData                                        |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | {"721005":"NO","720931":"1156","720940":"aegiseng",}    |
|  2 | {"721005":"NO","720931":"1156","720940":"aegiseng",}    |
|  3 | {"721005":"NO","720931":"50253","720940":"d1-gateway",} |
|  4 | {"721005":"NO","720931":"11102","720940":"uxinfra",}    |
|  5 | {"720931":"1152","720940":"zappops-notify",}            |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to remove the last occurring comma from the jsonData i.e **',}'** to **'}'**

I tried

```
mysql> update formjson set jsonData=CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ',}' FROM jsonData),'}') where jsonData like '%,}';
```

Above is working.

But is there any other way to do this in MySQL, using regexp user defined functions etc?

Comment: `CONCAT(TRAILING, '}')` instead of CONCAT(TRAILING, ',}')` should do it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Didn't understand, how it would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
UPDATE formjson SET jsonData=REPLACE(jsonData, ',}', '}') WHERE jsonData LIKE '%,}'
```